# Type Error in Jquery ajax function using submit handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am validating a text box using jquery validate plug-in, but when I submit the button it is not validating.  It is showing an error at submit Handler in firebug:

**Error**

```
TypeError:$(...)validate is not a function
```

**Code**

```
function saveData() {
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#form1").validate({

        rules: {

            txtName: {

                required: true

            }

        },

        message: {

            txtName: {

                required: "Field should not be empty"
            }

        },


        submitHandler: function (form) {

            var txtName = $("#txtName").val();
            var txtEmail = $("#txtEmail").val();
            var txtSurName = $("#txtSurName").val();
            var txtMobile = $("#txtMobile").val();
            var txtAddress = $("#txtAddress").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: location.pathname + "/saveData",
                data: "{Name:'" + txtName + "',SurName:'" + txtSurName + "',Email:'" + txtEmail + "',Mobile:'" + txtMobile + "',Address:'" + txtAddress + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "jsondata",
                async: "true",
                success: function (response) {

                    $(".errMsg ul").remove();
                    var myObject = eval('(' + response.d + ')');
                    if (myObject > 0) {
                        bindData();
                        $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Data saved successfully</li></ul>");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Opppps something went wrong.</li></ul>");
                    }
                    $(".errMsg").show("slow");
                    clear();

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                }


            });


        }

    });

    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        $("#form1").submit()

    });


});
```

}

I am calling this function in a button click. Please help me with this.

my design page of button fields is

Comment: `dataType`  from any one (xml, json, script, or html)

Comment: Can I see the rest of the code, because this seems alright. You don't have a place where you call something like this: `$("some-css-selector")validate` instead of `$("some-css-selector").validate` ?

Comment: please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/

Comment: 1)  You have not included jQuery or the plugin properly, otherwise `.validate()` would be recognized.  And 2)  `.validate()` is the plugin's _initialization_ method and therefore would **not** belong inside a function, `saveData`, that presumably gets triggered every time the submit button is clicked.  Just put `.validate()` in your DOM ready event handler.

Comment: There is no jQuery Validate plugin included in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/).

Comment: Your jsFiddle also needs to include the RENDERED markup as seen by the browser.  It's not going to parse your ASP code!

Comment: i updated my fiddle , i added validation plugin,,there is only hidden field in asp markup code, which is not necessary for our scenario

Comment: @user3452210, you have a whole bunch of errors as outlined in my answer below and fixed in this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of issues...

1)  You are not including the jQuery Validate plugin at all in your jsFiddle and if your comments are correct, you cannot include jQuery *after* the plugins.  jQuery gets included *first*, then any jQuery plugins.

2)  Your ID selector is wrong.  In your `<form>` tag, you have `id="form1"` but in your jQuery selector, you have `#Form1`.  This is **case-sensitive**.

3)  The jQuery validate plugin mandates that the inputs have unique `name` attributes.  You don't have any `name` attributes at all.  This is going to be a game-stopper.  The plugin will not work without a `name` attribute on each `input` element to be validated.

4)  The `messages` option is spelled `"messages"`.  You've misspelled it as `"message"`.

5)  You don't need an inline click handler on your button.  Just make it a `type="submit"` and allow the plugin to handle it automatically.  This means that you do not need to wrap `.validate()` inside another function.  Just put it inside a DOM ready event handler so the form is setup and ready as soon as the page loads.

**This one gets you closer:  http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/2/**

---

**EDIT based on commnets:**

To submit using the click of a `type="button"` would only require a `click` handler to capture the button.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() {
    $("#form1").submit();
});
```

OR

```
$("#btnSave").on('click', function() {
    $("#form1").submit();
});
```

Although, I don't understand the point of this, as ultimately, the only thing inside your `click` handler is a `submit`.  In other words, simply using a `type="submit"` button would have the exact same functionality without needing any `click` handler function.

(In [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/33/), `"function"` was misspelled as `"functioin"`.  I think you just need to slow down as many of your issues have to do with spelling.)

Comment: Thanks for the help!! But u have used type="submit" . I want to do validation on a button click  , if i used the button click it is not working see this http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/33/

Comment: @user3452210, your problems seem to stem from a general carelessness.  In the jQuery `click` handler in [the last jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/33/), you misspelled `"function"` as `"functioin"`.  Otherwise, it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/dxEEe/40/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you haven't loaded the jquery validation plugin. It tells you that there is no validate function on the jquery object.

Comment: I have added "jquery.validate.js" "jquery.validate.min.js" plugins to my design page which is registration.aspx

Comment: you should not add both, .min.js is just a minified version of the other.

Comment: I tried with either one of them!! still nothing happend!!

Comment: @user3452210, are you including jQuery ***BEFORE*** the jQuery Validate plugin?

Comment: @user3452210, that's backwards!  jQuery gets included **first**, then the plugins.